# MySQL 8.0.15 Creating an array

Tags: php, mysql

We have just upgraded our server and we now have MySQL 8.0.15, previously we had MySQL 5.5.58
We had a procedure to create an array, but on the new server it dont seem to happen. I am just wondering if the procedure is different in a newer version of MySQL?
Thanks
Paul.

```
$save_path = "C:\\export\\"; 
if($values['AutoExport']){
    $data = 
    array(
    "JobNo"=>$values['JobNo'],
    "ContactEmail"=>$values['ContactEmail'];

    $domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $domtree->xmlStandalone = true;
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("table");
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);
    $xmlRow = $xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement("row"));
    foreach ( $data as $data_key => $child_data ) 
        $xmlRow->appendChild($domtree->createElement(htmlspecialchars($data_key),htmlspecialchars($child_data)));
    $domtree->formatOutput = true;
    $domtree->save($save_path."Job_".$values["JobNo"].".xml");
}
```

Comment: What excatly is not working? Is PHP not executing the code? Or where does it crash/stop? Can you tell the line in code where the result isn't what you are expecting?

Comment: How is this question related to *MySQL*? There's no database access code here.

Comment: Its OK I rebuilt the server and used a different version of PHP and it seems to work now. Thanks